# Looking for a Japanese English-dubbed boy and giant robot film

Tags: story-identification, robots, kaiju

This is **not** *Johnny Sokko*.

This **live-action** movie (or TV show) was about an hour long, likely produced in the **late 80's/early 90's**, and VERY low budget.

A Japanese boy and his giant **multi-colored** robot fight monsters. There was eerie Asian music throughout the video. I can't remember what the monsters looked like. If you can think of questions that might stir up additional memories, please feel free to ask. Any help is greatly appreciated, as this is driving me insane trying to figure out the name of the movie/show.

It was a humanoid robot. I believe it was a stunt guy in a suit, but I could be wrong. I can't remember the exact colors - just that it was multi-colored. I think it was a young boy, possibly a teenager. He directed the robot, but I think he just said the commands, not anything involving a controller. Thanks for the questions! Sorry I can't be more descriptive.

Comment: I assume that it was a humanoid robot? Did he look like a stunt guy in a suit rather than a puppet, CG, or animation? Do you remember what sort of colors for the robot? Was this a young boy? A teenager? A young adult? Did the boy participate in the fights? Direct the robot? Stand scared on the outskirts?

Comment: Yes, it was a humanoid. I believe it was a stunt guy in a suit, but I could be wrong. I can't remember the exact colors - just that it was multi-colored. I think it was a young boy, possibly a teenager. He directed the robot, but I think he just said the commands, not anything involving a controller. Thanks for the questions! Sorry I can't be more descriptive.

Comment: @Joseph is this robot familiar? http://backy.blog.bbiq.jp/blog/images/2011/09/12/sodrxo5f.jpg

Answer (score 5):

You may be thinking of *[Brain 17](https://archive.org/details/Brain17)*, a compilation film of *[Daitetsujin 17](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daitetsujin_17)*.

> Brain is the world's greatest computer, and also the most intelligent being on planet Earth. One day, Brain decides to abandon its terrestrial moorings, and it's up to The Defenders to track it down. Unfortunately, Brain has developed an amazing army of deadly giant robots, including one with a huge "17" emblazoned on its chest-plate, with which it plans to subjugate its creators. A young boy whose family was killed by Brain's followers manages to activate Daitetsujin 17, which thereafter comes to his rescue whenever he is in danger from Brain's minions.

[image: Daitetsujin 17]

Answer (score 1):

A possibility would be Jet Jaguar from Godzilla versus Megalon.  The Robot is, indeed, multi-colored and is influenced by a small boy, the inventor's younger brother.  Jet Jaguar becomes self-controlling when needed and reverts to the inventor's control when the crisis has passed.  He can fly and can alter his size at will.  There is a plot description from Wikipedia here; [Wiki Jet Jaguar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Godzilla_vs._Megalon#Plot)

[image]